# How to connect gps to internet and track the device

Tags: gps, communication

I have a gps device that is attached to my car now from my home i want to know where my car is presently at and on which route is it moving,want to have the complete route info.
i have no idea how gps connects to google map and all.Can you please guide me the above query and is there any free tool available for it.